# Almost sure convergence in strong law of large numbers.

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Strong Law of Large Numbers is often stated as
$$\overline{X}_n\ \xrightarrow{a.s.}\ \mu \qquad\textrm{when}\ n \to \infty$$
or
$$\Pr\!\left( \lim_{n\to\infty}\overline{X}_n = \mu \right) = 1$$
for $\overline{X}_n$ - average of $n$ i.i.d. random variables with mean $\mu$.

It seems to me from the definition, that order to have a notion of "almost sure convergence" we must have a sequence of random variables $X_i$ on the same probability space; at the same time $\overline{X}_n$ is a random variable on the product of probability spaces of the first $n$ of the $X_i$'s. Of course we can think of all $\overline{X}_k$'s as living on the $n$'th product for $k \leq n$, but to consider all $n$ at the same time, we would have to have an infinite product.  This would make sense, but seems somewhat complicated (infinite product spaces!). So, am I missing something, or is this what's going on and all elementary introductions (and wikipedia) just supress this point?

Edit: Ok, so the original question was a bit misleading - and the clarification is a bit long, see comments below, but I decided to post it also as an answer (it overlaps a bit with the accepted one).

Comment: For anyone looking: Stroock's "An Intorduction to Markov Process" is "honest" -- starts with a family of Bernoulli i.i.d. random variables and immediately says "The existence [of such a family] is the content of §6.2.1" and indeed a full proof (with sample space $\Omega=\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{Z}^+}$) is in that section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Independence concerns random variables defined on a common probability space. To see this, assume that $X:(\Omega,\mathcal F)\to(E,\mathcal E)$ and $Y:(\Psi,\mathcal G)\to(E,\mathcal E)$ are random variables. To show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, one would consider events such as
$$
[X\in B]\cap[Y\in C]=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\in B\}\cap\{\psi\in\Psi\mid Y(\psi)\in C\}.
$$
Unless $(\Omega,\mathcal F)=(\Psi,\mathcal G)$, this simply does not make sense.

> ...$\overline{X}_n$ is a random variable on the product of probability spaces of the first $n$ of the $X_i$'s...

Not at all. The random variable $\overline{X}_n$ can only be defined on the common probability space which every $X_n$ is defined on. To define sums $X+Y$ such as the ones every $\overline{X}_n$ requires, one considers
$$X+Y:\omega\mapsto X(\omega)+Y(\omega).
$$

> Maybe one needs infinite product spaces to even talk about a sequence of i.i.d. Xi's

One does not, for the reasons above. If one insists on using a product space, the construction is as follows. Assume that $X_i:(\Omega_i,\mathcal F_i)\to(E,\mathcal E)$, consider $\Omega=\prod\limits_i\Omega_i$, $\mathcal F=\mathop{\otimes}_i\mathcal F_i$ and, for every $i$, the random variable $Z_i:(\Omega,\mathcal F)\to(E,\mathcal E)$ defined by $Z_i(\omega)=X_i(\omega_i)$ for every $\omega=(\omega_i)_i$ in $\Omega$. Then, if each $(\Omega_i,\mathcal F_i)$ is endowed with a probability $P_i$ such that the distribution $P_i\circ X_i^{-1}$ does not depend on $i$ and if $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ is endowed with the probability $P=\mathop{\otimes}_iP_i$, then indeed $(Z_i)$ is i.i.d. with common distribution 
$$
P\circ Z_i^{-1}=P_i\circ X_i^{-1}.
$$
One may find this kind of construction fascinating. Usually though, after a while, the feeling passes... :-) and one sticks to the *modus operandi* most probabilists adopt, which is to consider that the exact nature of $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ is irrelevant and that all that counts are the image measures on the *target space*.

Comment: I agree what I wrote is either wrong or misleading. Let me try to explain/ask things better. 1) A random variable $X$  on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ induces a canonical random variable $\hat{X}$ variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal F) \times\Psi,\mathcal G)$ for any probability space  $(\Psi,\mathcal G)$, by postcomposing combining $X$ with projection. The two random variables are equidistributed. Moreover, if $Y$ is a random variable on $(\Psi,\mathcal G)$, then $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{Y}$ are independent. It is in this sense that I meant that the averages are defined on product spaces.

Comment: So, one can obtain a sequence of i.i.d. random variables by "lifting"  random variables to product spaces. On the other hand, if I have two i.i.d. variables $X, Y$ on some probability space, I get a map from whatever probability space these are defined on to $(E,\mathcal E)\times(E,\mathcal E)$. My intuition is that for them to be i.i.d. this map needs to be onto (the support of the distribution squared, but let's assume the support is all of $E$).  So the space on which $X$ and $Y$ are defined is at least "as large as" $E^2$.

Comment: Finally, to have an infinite sequence of i.i.d. random variables the common probability space on which they are all defined (as you rightly point out) must be "at least as large as" $E^\infty$.  Certainly an infinite product space would work, but the above convinces me that no "smaller" space would really do. Am I wrong? Of course the space may look different than an infinite product, but (at least for the discussion of the Strong Law of Large numbers) one is really looking at the $E^\infty$ image of it... Comments?

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: Yes, it seems proper to forget about the technicalities - after you understand them well enough. I accepted the answer, but just as an afterthought - do you know _any_ example of infinite i.i.d. sequence _not_ coming from an infinite product?

Comment: Sure: $X_n$ the $n$th bit of the binary expansion of a number uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$.

Comment: That's the same infinite product construction, very slightly disguised. Anything less obviously equivalent to the infinite product? (Extra challenge: something where $X_i$'s have a PDF on $\mathbb{R}$?) :)

Comment: You know, you should really define "the same". If you want to say that every i.i.d. model is *isomorphic* to a product model, the remark is true (trivially) and (almost) the definition. Hence surely you have a more interesting notion in mind... Another example: $X_n=U_1+\cdots+U_n\pmod{1}$ where the sequence $(U_n)$ is i.i.d uniform on $(0,1)$.

Comment: I was not trying to be formal (my fault :) ). However, if you insist, "the same" should be either 1)isomorphic or 2)isomorphic mod 0 or 3) isomorphic in a suitable category (does such a thing exist?). I would love to discuss all of these (or, rather, how to weaken them appropriately, since I think they are all trivially _false_ because one can always add extra stuff and keep the iid sequence; there are other things that are trivially true but they are not quite the same). But perhaps we should move to chat or something...

Answer (score 1):

Why would we need product spaces. $X_i$'s being random variables are measurable functions. Then consider the $\sigma$-field generated by $X_1,\cdots,X_n$. The $\bar{X}_n$ is measurable with respect to this $\sigma$-field. Hence $\bar{X}_n$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma$-field  generated by $X_1,X_2,\cdots$. I think that is all you need.

Comment: I guess you are right, in the sense that I should have worded my concern differently. My problem is that to have $X_i$'s i.i.d. I already need an infinite product space. More concretely,  if $X_1$ and $X_2]$ are distributed as uniform on $[0,1]$ then  the probability space has to map to $[0,1]^2$ (surjectively?); the smallest such (initial in category of probability spaces mapping to $[0,1]^2$) is $[0,1]^2$. For $X_1$, $X_2$, ... $X_3$ it's $[0,1]^3$... So the need for infinite product starts earlier... Or is this also avoidable?

Answer (score 0):

A random variable  $X:(\Omega,\mathcal F, P_\Omega)\to(E,\mathcal E)$ induces a canonical random variable $\hat{X}:(\Omega \times \Psi,\mathcal F \otimes \mathcal G, P_\omega\times P_\Psi)\to(E,\mathcal E)$  on the product with any probability space $(\Psi,\mathcal G, P_\psi)$ by precomposing $X$ with projection. The two random variables $X$ and $\hat{X}$ are equidistributed. I addition, if  $Y:(\Psi,\mathcal G, P_\Psi)\to(E,\mathcal E)$ is a random variable on $(\Psi,\mathcal G, P_\psi)$, then $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{Y}$ are independent. Moreover this works even if $Y=X$ - we get $\hat{X}_1$ and $\hat{X}_2$ by composing with different projections. This is a "cheap way" to get i.i.d. random variables.

Now, for a pair of random variables on the same probability space $(P, \mathcal P, P_P)$ (as is the case with i.i.d. variables) valued in $(E,\mathcal E)$ I get a map from $P$ to $E^2$. Moreover, under some reasonable conditions the image of this map is big. (For example, assuming $E$ is topological space and $\mathcal E$ is the Borel sigma-algebra, and then assuming that supports of $X$ and $Y$ are all of $E$, image of this map is dense in  $E^2$).

In this spirit, if I have an infinite sequence of i.i.d. random variables, then the space on which they are defined will map to $E^\infty$, and under same assumptions this map will again have a big image. To me this says that the space they are defined on is "big", in some sense as big as the infinite product. In fact other than "fake" example like $[0,1)$ with $X_i(x)=\{i\text{th binary digit of x} \}$ which is just $\{0,1\}^\infty$ in disguise I don't know any way to get an infinite sequence of i.i.d.s on anything other than a product space.

Comment: "then X^ and Y^ are independent" No. This depends very much on the probability measure one considers on the product space.

Comment: "I don't know any way to get an infinite sequence of i.i.d.s on anything other than a product space." There is an example in the comments to my answer.

Comment: Sure, I meant "the product", as in  "the product in the category of probability spaces", as in "the product measure".

Comment: Yeah well, since you mention categories, note that there is no probability space in your answer, only measurable spaces.

Comment: Ok, sure, one can be more explicit. I edited it.

Comment: Ah, I have now read more about problems with category-theoretic formulation of probability, I think I see what you mean. Fascinating stuff.